# ASP.NET content disappears onClick in GridView

Tags: asp.net, button, gridview

I have a GridView with a Button in a TemplateField. When I click one of the Buttons generated by the TemplateField the master page content appears but no content from the page I am actually loading is appearing. I even have an OutputLabel (for debugging purpose) which is outside anything related to the GridView or the div containing the GridView, and it doesn't either.

Content page:

```
<%@ Page Title="Administration" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Admin.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainCon" Runat="Server">
    <div id="container" class="left-margin">
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="CustomGetAllUsers" TypeName="Helper"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="UserGrid" CssClass="UserList" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AllowCustomPaging="True" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" style="margin: auto">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Height="50"/>
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
            <Columns>
               <asp:TemplateField runat="server">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" Text="Rediger" BorderColor="LightBlue" BackColor="LightGray" BorderWidth="3px" BorderStyle="Solid" OnClick="EditButton_Click"/>
                   </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="OutputLabel" />
</asp:Content>
```

And the code executed on click:

```
protected void EditButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Username", gvr.Cells[2].Text);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    Response.Redirect("~/UserAdmin.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Does UserAdmin.aspx actually have anything to display?Have you tried placing a break point on Page_Load of UserAdmin.aspx, is it being hit?

Comment: It's is not hit as the page does not redirect! The address still points towards Admin.aspx. And yes the UserAdmin.aspx has something to display.

Comment: Have you tried Server.Transfer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found out the solution. I changed the TemplateField to a ButtonField with CommandName="Edit" and made an OnRowCommand for the GridView.

The whole problem was that it did not call the appropriate method in the codebehind. Now it calls this method which works as it should.

```
protected void UserList_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        String s = (String) UserGrid.DataKeys[index].Value;
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Username", s);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        Response.Redirect("UserAdmin.aspx");
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help anyway!